# trying to run jiunt test cases spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I tried to run junit test cases with spring boot application. But there is bean creating issue due to not finding setProxyTargetClass on PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor package.
An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V but it does not exist.
Below is my stack trace.

Description:

```
An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor, is available from the following locations:
 

 jar:file:/C:/Users/r2um2k/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.8/spring-dao-2.0.8.jar!/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/r2um2k/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/r2um2k/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-dao/2.0.8/spring-dao-2.0.8.jar
```

Action:

```
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor

2020-07-30 12:49:55.741 ERROR 17624 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@73afe2b7] to prepare test instance [com.fanniemae.acquisitions.cdds.datafeed.task.UcdpCompDataFeedTaskHelperTest@5b251fb9]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/dao/PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setProxyTargetClass(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:228) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.con
```

Here is my POM file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fanniemae.acquisitions.cdds</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucdp-company-datafeed</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ucdp-company-datafeed</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <ucdp-ram-common.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</ucdp-ram-common.version>
        <common.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</common.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-ibatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ibatis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.6</version> -->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pojava</groupId>
            <artifactId>pojava</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>42.2.11</version> -->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>addressing</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <type>mar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fanniemae.acquisitions.cdds.internal.dependentjar</groupId>
            <artifactId>rahas</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <type>mar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>wlthint3client</artifactId>
            <version>12.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                
            </plugin>
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add code which causes the problem in addition to the configuration which you've provided?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dependency to `spring-ibatis` - this is for Spring v 2 and you are using version 5! Look at the release date, this is from 2008.

`mybatis-spring` is enough for spring integration of mybats ([see here](https://mybatis.org/spring/))

Comment: I need this spring-ibatis dependency. It is referred by another internal project. So cannot remove it.

Comment: Then you have to explain your project structure. Because if it's a different project, I don't see the dependency here? This is just the POM for `cdp-company-datafeed`, so where do you need `spring-ibatis`

Comment: I have not put intentionally in pom the dependency as it is internal to the company and should have  security. the dependent project is also using mybatis. I think that they are using ibatis session factory instead of mybatis session factory. Template which is used in DAO layer should be from mybatis session i guess.

Comment: I still don't see why you would include a transitive dependency anyway. If Project A depends on Project B and B on spring-ibatis - then why include spring-ibatis in Project A? Your project setup is messed up. Check which spring version your internal dependency uses. You won't be able to get it to run if you mix incompatible versions. Period.